# Python method that makes your instance of your class to be indexable (add [])

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am struggling with one of the practice questions I got. I might be asking a question that is too easy for most of you, but I couldn't find the right answer by reading the text book. 
I found an answer through google search, but I'd like to make sure that I found the right answer to the question.

> If you'd like an instance of your class to be "index-able" (that is,
>   the ability to add []'s in order to retrieve an element, like a list,
>   dict, tuple, etc.), then you must define and implement a method called
>   ______.

I think that the answer is

> ___getitem____

but I couldn't find this in my textbook, so I would hugely appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try implementing that? Read e.g. [the data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)? What makes you think it might *not* be `__getitem__`?

Comment: exact link is https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Comment: There seems to be some miscommunication between you and whoever gave you that practice question. If this is not mentioned in your textbook, then apparently the instructor is expecting you to have read something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed looking for `__getitem__`. You can read about it in the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). Here is an example of how to use it:

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return f'This is item with index {index}'

f = Foo()
print(f[1])
```

```
'This is item with index 1'
```